# Gcloud Sql postgres Timezone issue

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I am facing issue with Postgres hosted on Gcloud SQL. I am using sequelize as ORM which generates query properly and when the query goes to Postgres timestamps are converted to UTC. I need them to be in IST.

earlier it was working fine with my sequelize config.

```
dialectOptions: {
      useUTC: false, // for reading from database
    },
    timezone: '+05:30', // for writing to database
```

I tried to run the direct query from Postgres CLI too. it was storing timestamps in UTC. I need my data to be displayed to the user in IST.

Also, I am not able to change postgresql.conf on cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access and change postgresql.conf on Google Cloud SQL. It's a managed service.

With MySql, it's possible to define default timezone with [Database flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags).
But it seems that is not already available for [PostgreSql](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags).

However, you can decide to store in UTC, and convert timezone before writing, and after reading from Cloud Sql.
Multi-locale software works like that, to be sure to adapt to every user localization.

Comment: yes, i already figured our that. I handled that at my ORM level